# Set a custom buttons font without being overridden by the value set in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, xcode6.1

I have a custom button, AdvisorButton.h and within the init I set the font of the button but I believe they are being overridden by the storyboard settings for the button.

Heres the implementation:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        [self initializationCodeMethod];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        [self initializationCodeMethod];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initializationCodeMethod
{

    if(self.tag == 1)
    {
        UIFont *theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINOT-Light" size:20];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:theFont];
    }
    else
    {
        UIFont *theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"VWHeadlineOT-Book" size:20];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:theFont];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The font objects are initialised properly and if i print them out the have value etc.

The problem is they are defined in the storyboard and I want to avoid referencing every button/label/textfield in their view controllers just to set the font.

Am I right in thinking that the storyboard values are being set after the init function call?

Any insight into this problem would prove useful!

EDIT:
Note that I checked the font before trying to set it, and its set to the default font from the storyboard which is fine.

I then check it again after it is supposedly set and its still the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

It turns out of the text of the object on the storyboard is anything other than the system default any changes are overridden by the storyboard settings.

I personally had attributed text with underline etc and it did not update.

I removed the attributes but left another font other than default and it failed to replace the font.

Therefore I set it back to default and it then allowed me to replace the font.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added your custom button class name in identity inspector section for corresponding button class in storyboard[image: Refer the image]

also try setting font in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        [self initializationCodeMethod];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in your custom button class

Comment: I have its of AdvisorButton class.

Comment: Reassign `self` and recreate it from scratch on each `drawRect`? That sounds like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString` includes one or more fonts itself. If you want to change the font, you have to recreate `NSAttributedString` with your desired font or remove it and use `UILabel.text` directly. In that case `UILabel.font` will have effect.

As a side effect, you can create attributed string without any font set, in that case probably `UILabel.font` would have effect. I noticed this behavior with `UIColor.textColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the fonts to the info.plist under:
"Fonts provided by application"
-   item 0 - yourfontname.OTF

Somehow the storyboard doesn't need this, but I needed it when I tried to change fonts programmatically.